# problem with taking a stream of character starting with integer

Tags: c

I'm trying to take in input a stream of characters that can be 0 or 1 but when I input a sequece the number are ignored unless I insert a non numerical character

here's my code

```
int mess = 0;
char getNum;

do {
    getNum = getc(stdin);
    printf("%d ", getNum);
    
    if(getNum - '0' == 0 || getNum - '0' == 1) {
        mess <<= 1;
        mess |= getNum - '0';
    }
} while(getNum != EOF && getNum != '\n');

printf("mess: %d", mess);
```

Comment: @MikeCAT, OP is using `getch` not `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is taking a single character input until `Enter` is pressed. You are only checking whether the entered character is `'0'` or `'1'`. Otherwise, you are ignoring it.

So, the program will calculate a decimal number with the binary digits you have entered and store it in mess.
So if you Enter `1010`, the value of `mess` will be `10`.

If you Enter `fgf1010hhj`, the value of `mess` will still be `10`.

If you Enter `987ffdg`, the value of `mess` will be `0` as there is no binary digits.

Comment: @jhvo Can you upload the whole code, please? I am getting 10. What I just did is inserted your code in a main() function.